# Обновить значение label

Tags: objective-c, ios

Для обновления значений в таблице используется self.tableView reloadData. Мне нужно подобным образом обновить текст меток (label). 
Вот набор меток

```
self.NameLabel.text = [self.PeopleDetail objectForKey:NAME_KEY];
   self.PhoneLabel.text = [self.PeopleDetail objectForKey:PHONE_KEY];

self.Emaillabel.text = [self.PeopleDetail objectForKey:EMAIL_KEY];
```

Comment: БЫДЩЬ >< мозг лопнул. Подробнее плз.

Answer (score 2):

```
 - (void) updateLabels
 {

// код по апдейту тут, который у тебя в вопросе

}
```

Вызывать функцию каждый раз, когда обновляется модель данных, или когда тебе там надо. У лейбла нет методов для релоада данных, надо делать все вручную. Я жу ответил тебе в контакте, не устроило?)

Comment: Просто здесь вопрос раньше чем в вконтакте задал. Спасибо.

Comment: @СлаваРаченко Вы забыли пометить ответ как правильный.